# Grails "bean:input" (bean fields) showing the wrong bean property

Tags: grails

Since we've updated to grails 2.0.1 (from 2.0.0) all of our beans shown via bean fields are incorrectly displayed as the first property of that "withBean" field. In the example I've posted below, all of [firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, contactNumber] are shown as just 'firstName' (we know it's not just the messages which are wrong because otherwise the 3rd property (dateOfBirth) would be a date picker, not just a text field).

Any potential workarounds or suggestions?

(plugins.bean-fields=1.0-RC3)

[image: Code]

[image]

Comment: That has been considered - but preferably we'd not like to change the many forms to use it.

Comment: @Don: You probably meant [grails-fields](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-fields) - the name was changed a while ago, and the one you linked to is not the original source, but a fork.  (Just for anyone else who happens upon this.)  Grails plugin page: http://grails.org/plugin/fields

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and have a work-around.

I has customised beanfield templates extracted into a gsp template called `/shared/_beanfieldConfig.gsp` , which I then included by rendering before calling any beans tags. e.g.

```
<g:render template="/shared/beanFieldConfig" />
<bean:withBean beanName='command'>
<bean:input property='username' />
```

This worked nicely in 1.3.7, and meant I could share beanFieldConfig between views.

When upgrading to 2.0.3, I enountered the same issue as the original question. I've found I can work around this by inlining the content of my `_beanFieldConfig` in each view.

Yuk, but at least it means I don't need rewrite all my views to use the replacement plugin (yet).

(edit)
Interestingly, although beanField config in a render'd template doesn't work, sticking it in a taglib DOES.

so, while previously I had in beanFieldConfig

```
<bean:inputTemplate>
<div class='input ${errors ? 'errors' : '' }'>
    ${label}
    ${field}
    <g:if test="${errors}">
        ${errors}
    </g:if>
</div>
</bean:inputTemplate>
```

If I define the equivalent tag -

```
def beanFieldConfig = {
    bean.inputTemplate { m ->
        m.with {
        """ <div class='input ${errors ? 'errors' : '' }'>
    ${label}
    ${field}
    ${errors ?: ''}
</div>"""}
    }
}
```

and then in my gsp  replace `<g:render template="/shared/beanFieldConfig" />` with `<g:beanFieldConfig/>`, it works.